# Missing routes.php File in New Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I downloaded Composer, installed Laravel, and started my first Laravel project to begin learning Laravel using the lessons on Laracast (great lessons). Lesson two covers routes. My new project does not have a routes.php file.

I deleted the composer and started again. Same thing. Tried two different computers. Same thing. I was using NetBeans so I tried using PHP Storm. Same thing. I tried making my own routes.php file but it doesn't seem to work right because I know nothing about Laravel at this point. I tried creating and saving the project in htdocs, and then the PHPStorm project folder, but again - no routes.php file.

Composer is saved here- C:\Users\myName\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin. I used composer global required "laravel/installer" in the command prompt to install Laravel. Any ideas?

Answer (score 137, accepted):

## The lastest version of Laravel doesn't have a routes.php file.

This 'routes.php' file was located in \app\Http in the older versions.

In the newer version, Laravel 5.3, we have a folder named 'routes', where we can find the following files:

- api.php
- console.php
- web.php

For this new version, the routes for your controllers, you can put inside web.php file

See the documentation about routing here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#basic-routing

The video lesson you are watching may be outdated.

Comment: Thanks, This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Thank You. This was helpful, because I was following a tutorial.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the magic of routes/api.php using Route  class while not using the class namespace?

Answer (score 12):

In the Latest Laravel they have removed common routes.php where as they have added different route files to better manage your application routes.

There is

1. **routes/web.php** : routes file which works similar to routes.php file where you can have your routes and all the POST routes in web.php file will be validated for the CSRF Token similar to normal Laravel Post route.
2. **routes/api.php** : routes file where you can have your Application's API routes, the URL will be *example.com/api/* Eg. If you have route *getUsers* then the API URL will be *example.com/api/getUsers*. The most important thing to notice is **POST** requests to an API url will not be validated for *CSRF Token*.
3. **routes/console.php** : routes file where you can define your Artisan commands which you can run from Laravel Artisan CLI.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel  new version don't have routes.php

**It** **has**

1.web.php 
  To create Web routes

2.api.php 
 if you are using front (js) framework then write routes here

3.console.php 
the console.php used for console commands and interaction with commands

Answer (score 2):

@Geraldo has answered it well but still something more you can learn-

In Laravel newer version, old types of routes.php file has deleted.

**Why removed:**

From Laravel announcement, it has done to give more flexibility to the routes.

**Solution:**

Now there, a route folder has added and inside that folder there are 4 files.

1. `web.php` -- The previous routes were in this files mainly. Here is where you can register web routes for your application.
2. `api.php` -- Here is where you can register API routes for your application.
3. `channels.php` -- Here you may register all of the event broadcasting channels that your application supports.
4. `console.php` -- For all of the console commands and interaction with commands.

See, now it is more flexible for you to add any API and then link it via it's `api.php` route file and normal route in `web.php` file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Listen**

Go to

- Project Folder Name --> app --> Http --> routes.php

You will find routes there.

**In the newer version**, 
Laravel 5.3, find folder named 'routes', where following files are present:

```
api.php
console.php
web.php
```

For this new version, the routes for your controllers, you can write in web.php file

Answer (score 0):

In version 5.6 there is no routes.php file under Http/Requests, from the docs:

> All Laravel routes are defined in your route files, which are located
>   in the routes directory. These files are automatically loaded by the
>   framework. The routes/web.php file defines routes that are for your
>   web interface. These routes are assigned the web middleware group,
>   which provides features like session state and CSRF protection. The
>   routes in routes/api.php are stateless and are assigned the api
>   middleware group.
>
> For most applications, you will begin by defining routes in your
>   routes/web.php file. The routes defined in routes/web.php may be
>   accessed by entering the defined route's URL in your browser. For
>   example, you may access the following route by navigating to 
>   http://your-app.test/user in your browser:
>
> Route::get('/user', 'UserController@index');

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Laravel new version doesn't have routes.php

1.web.php To create Web routes

2.api.php if you are using front (js) framework then write routes here

3.console.php the console.php used for console commands and interaction with commands

Comment: Can you explain how this answer differs from the several other answers, including the one that has been accepted and upvoted over 100 times?